# Use md-slider to select range

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I've used md-slider(Material2) in Angular2. I can select a number between two number, But is there any way to select range?

[image: Below image for single number selection]

Comment: Seriously there isn't any proper slider component with range...

Answer (score 1):

According to [API](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/slider), there is no such functionality right now.

Here is alternative small lib - [angular2 slider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-slider-component).

Comment: Can be a nice temporary fix, unless you need touch support, which this lib unfortunately lacks...